# RewriteRule not working as expected - htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My   `.htaccess` is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pg/(.*)$ /manage/product_groups/$1
```

I want to redirect each URL with `pg/fetchPG` as 1st and 2nd URL segment like

```
http://website.com/pg/fetchPG?name=Name_here
```

to

```
http://website.com/manage/product_groups/fetchPG?name=Name_here
```

I also want any URL other than that, should be redirected to `http://website.net`

I tried to do this by writing some code in PHP but it performs `302` redirect. So this is not I want.

mod_rewrite logs are as follows

```
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920251 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc588c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/pg -> /var/www/html/pg/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920306 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc588c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/pg/fetchPG -> pg/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920314 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc588c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^pg/(.*)$' to uri 'pg/fetchPG'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920338 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc588c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/] rewrite 'pg/fetchPG' -> 'manage/product_groups/fetchPG'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920349 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc588c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/] add per-dir prefix: manage/product_groups/fetchPG -> /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920363 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc588c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/ with /
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920375 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc588c0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/] internal redirect with /manage/product_groups/fetchPG [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920959 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups -> /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920976 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG -> product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920984 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '(^|/)\\.' to uri 'product_groups/fetchPG'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920992 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups -> /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.920999 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG -> product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921006 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'product_groups/fetchPG'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921020 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups -> /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921027 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG -> product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921041 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'product_groups/fetchPG'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921055 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups -> /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921063 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG -> product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921069 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'product_groups/fetchPG'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921085 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] rewrite 'product_groups/fetchPG' -> 'index.php?/product_groups/fetchPG'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921093 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] split uri=index.php?/product_groups/fetchPG -> uri=index.php, args=/product_groups/fetchPG
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921105 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/html/manage/index.php
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921114 2017] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/html/manage/index.php -> /manage/index.php
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921120 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc5886330/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] internal redirect with /manage/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921192 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921202 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '(^|/)\\.' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921211 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921217 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921226 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921240 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921255 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/manage/index.php -> index.php
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921262 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
[Sat Feb 25 17:18:03.921274 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 8296] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 39.32.81.36:26799] 39.32.81.36 - - [website.com/sid#7efcd2c4ec80][rid#7efcc58794c0/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/html/manage/] pass through /var/www/html/manage/index.php
```

Comment: Is /var/www/html/manage/product_groups/fetchPG the correct final path?

Answer (score 2):

Edit/logging: To see what is happening, [enable logging for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) in your server's config file. Let me know if you need help finding that. In the file (perhaps httpd.conf), find the `LogLevel` directive and add `rewrite:trace2` to the line. Keep in mind you will have to restart apache for the logging to take effect.

First, I suspect your solution is in the use of [RewriteBase directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). Without it, it's hard to know what prefix is prepended to your substitution. In a file setting like .htaccess, it may be that your leading slash on the substitution is causing issues.

Second, use [the `QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) to append the original query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^pg/(.*)$ manage/product_groups/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: What was the error before? You may need to play with the RewriteBase path. Also: Can you get logging going? Should I add logging instructions to the answer - to see what is going on?

Comment: There is a Codeigniter project inside `manage` folder. Previously I had some other error, now its CodeIgniter's 404 error. BTW if I directly put `manage/product_groups` in place of `pg` in browser, URL works.

Comment: Now its CodeIgniter's 404 error, that means the newly re-written URL is wrong, the 404 page I am seeing, is displayed when I put in wrong URL in browser.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to remove the leading slash from the replacement pattern.

Comment: Its still showing same Codeigniter's 404 error page

Comment: If you enable logging for mod_rewrite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136640/discussion-between-umair-and-chris-trahey).

Comment: Thanks - I moved them to your question where they are more appropriate